# Object Adding to Array

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I have a EJB object that needs to added to a array list. After adding to the array, all the objects in the list refer to the last object.

```
private @EJB
    JiraissueFacade jiraissueFacade;


for (MajorEvent mjrEvent : listOfMajorEvent) {
                System.out.println("Mjr evnet id"+mjrEvent.getJissueId());
                Jiraticket jiraticket_mjr = new Jiraticket();
                jiraticket_mjr =  jiraissueFacade.findByID(mjrEvent
                        .getJissueId());
                jiraticket_mjr.setSelected(mjrEvent.getFlag());

                System.out.println("Jiraticket pkey :"+jiraticket_mjr.getPkey());


                listOfJiraticket.add(jiraticket_mjr);
            }
```

## Output

When it print pkey in the console, it prints the individual object but when i get the final list from the "listOfJiraticket" all are referring to last object. How to correct it?

Comment: Post the code you use to demonstrate to yourself that "all are referring to last object".

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik can you tell me how to correct it.

Comment: What is an "EJB object", are they JPA entities? If so, are `Jiraticket` entities? If so, is `Jiraticket#getPkey()` a getter for the Id, or just a getter for the database primarykey, or even something else? Have you taken care of properly implementing hashcode and equals on the `Jiraticket`? There are many more questions, but that is a start. Another one would be, why abbreviate Major with mjr?